# How to access files shown in UAC window without closing UAC window on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

If I double click on an installer file it loads some exe files first, then UAC pops up. When I close the UAC dialog to see the downloaded files I cannot proceed with the installation. Is it possible to access and see/check these exe files without having to close the UAC window?

Comment: No. the UAC prompt screen is purposely a separate session so that malware can't just click the button. it is not possible to switch back and forth between these sessions.

Comment: Just disable UAC, User Account Control is only good at annoying you. I have disabled Windows Defender, Smart Screen, Security Center, UAC and others, and my computer is still fine.

Comment: You may try to disable UAC for Specific Applications. For your reference:https://superuser.com/questions/1607838/disable-uac-for-a-specific-program-windows-10