# New Windows 10 account not seen as admin despite same config as old account

Tags: windows-10, administrator, uac

New Windows 10 account not seen as admin despite same config as old account

I have two accounts on my computer.

Both are admin.

Both have UAC set to "Notify me only apps try to make changes to my computer (default) / Don't notify me when I make changes to Windows settings.", therefore UAC isn't a relevant factor.

However, only one gets treated like an admin. I'm running programs that requires admin to work. In the first account, it just works. In the second account, I have to right click and run as administrator.

How can I have the second account treated like the first account? What exactly is the state of the first account (UAC enabled but it doesn't have any prompts?)

What I've tried from looking at:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-wont-recognize-me-as-administrator/b05b36ba-8b10-4d1a-869c-23403f7da72e

#1. Create a new account with command line "net user {username} /active:yes"

This has no effect. It creates a third account with the same behaviour as the second.

#2.
Open up registry editor and go here:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
Change EnableLUA to 0

This does not answer the question. The first account runs fine without this setting change.

UPDATE: Resolved as far as I'm concerned:

The whole purpose of this was to get a task running in startup (and avoid manually opening it each time). Assuming it's some unknown registry setting (I don't seem to have Group Policy), I got the task running a different way following these instructions:
[Disable UAC for a specific program (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1607838/disable-uac-for-a-specific-program-windows-10)

Also the main purpose of switching to a new account was to change the username (and all corresponding files), but that's also a complicated procedure.

UPDATE:

Unsure what changes I could have made, I get the impression there is a "built-in administrator account" (the first one), which is treated differently than regular administrator accounts.

Comment: I'm running programs that requires admin to work. In the first account, it just works. In the second account, I have to right click and run as administrator. Third new account works like second.  ... There were group policy or registry changes to the first account because the third account is operating normally.

Comment: You are aware that those UAC settings don’t actually disable UAC? If one of these accounts are the built-in Administrator account that would be why the behavior is different

Comment: Admin accounts still need "run as admin" in order for something to actually run as admin. You've made some change to your "working" account that makes this not happen there. The other account is functioning normally.

Comment: The builtin Administrator by default intentionally doesn’t have UAC enabled which is the reason you had to change the registry key.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author considers the issue has resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: built-in administrator and regular administrator accounts behave differently.