# How to set an application to run as administrator from cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know the question might be confusing, but I want to generate a .bat that (dynamically) will tick all the .exe's in a folder to run as administrator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are the Administrator there is only a UAC requirement to address (never bothered). If this is for a regular user, what you want cannot be done.

Comment: @John It would be for an administrator user, but I wonder if there is any command to do it from a .bat

Comment: You can use Task Scheduler. Make a Task, use elevated permissions, run the Task from a batch file. https://superuser.com/questions/1607838/disable-uac-for-a-specific-program-windows-10/1607854#1607854

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Run as Administrator" Compatibility setting seems to be stored in the registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
```

You'll want to add a String value with the **full program path** as its name and `~ RUNASADMIN` as its value.

To do this from a batch file? I would try...

```
reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82\vim.exe" /d "~ RUNASADMIN"
```

And to run this on each file...

```
for /r %%i in (*.exe) do reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%%i" /d "~ RUNASADMIN"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brian. Just a note: I had to replace %%i by %i, cause I was getting an error there. It worked but I would like (I don't know if that is possible) to have active the checked option under "Change settings for all users". Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run the same command replacing `HKCU` with `HKLM`, which will switch Current User to Local Machine. For me, %%i worked. Strange. Although, I think you then need to run the batch file as an administrator.

Comment: Thanks! with HKLM it is all I needed. Yeah, it is strange but I was running the batch as an administrator so... Not sure why, but it is working with %i so.. Thanks again Brian