# Run app with admin privileges when invoked by 'open with' in context menu

Tags: administrator, context-menu, elevation

I know you can [use Task Scheduler to make a shortcut that opens an application as admin without the UAC prompt](https://superuser.com/q/1607838/916452), which is great, but I have certain apps that I typically open to edit system files etc, and therefore will more often use the context menu to 'open with'... which bypasses said shortcut.

I can see that task scheduler has triggers, so I'm wondering if maybe one of those will do this, but I can't find one that will. Is there a way to set an app to always run with admin privileges when invoked by the context menu in this way without just straight-up forcing it to always run elevated (which I understand is a security issue)?

Comment: If you invoke an app through the Send To context menu, you can use a shortcut with the Advanced option to Run as Administrator. For security, you still get the UAC dialog, though.